# C++ REST SDKでAuthorizationヘッダが指定できない

Tags: c++, twitter, rest

[この質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/55176/casablanca%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)と同じ内容ですが、状況が変わりましたので、再度質問させていただきます。

C++ REST SDK を使用してTwitterのOAuth認証を行いたいのですが、Authorizationヘッダーを指定したときに例外が投げられます。try-catchで例外を捕まえてみると、`WinHttpAddRequestHeaders: 87`とのコードが出ていました。

ネットで調べてみると、ヘッダーの文字数の上限(56)に達している？との[解説](https://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2408802)がありました。
しかしながら、[ここ](https://syncer.jp/Web/API/Twitter/REST_API/)のサイトにありますように、Authorizationヘッダーの内容は明らかに56文字を超えています。

この問題はどのように解決したらいいのでしょうか。
以下にコード（.hppファイル）を載せますので、回答して頂けると幸いです。

あちらこちらでバラバラな質問をしてしまい申し訳ありません。

```
#pragma once

#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <locale>
#include <winstring.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>
#include <time.h>
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"libeay32.lib") 

using namespace std;
using namespace web;
using namespace web::http;
using namespace web::http::client;

#define REST_POST_PATH "C:\\ProgramData\\System72\\CAIOS\\CAIOS\\REST_POST_RESPONSE.json"
#define REST_GET_PATH "C:\\ProgramData\\System72\\CAIOS\\CAIOS\\REST_GET_RESPONSE.json"
#define TWITTER_TWEET_URL "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
#define TWITTER_TIMELINE_URL "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"

typedef enum {
    POST,
    GET
} METHOD;

enum CodePageID : unsigned int {
    ANSI = CP_ACP,  // ANSI
    OEM = CP_OEMCP, // OEM(依存)
    MAC = CP_MACCP, // MAC
    UTF7 = CP_UTF7, // UTF-7
    UTF8 = CP_UTF8  // UTF-8
};

struct Request {
    string url;
    string post;
    string header;
};

struct TwitterAPI_Keys {
    string Consumer_Key     = "";
    string Consumer_Sec     = "";
    string Accesstoken      = "";
    string Accesstoken_Aec  = "";
};

namespace CAIOS {

    namespace String {

        static string UTF8_to_SJIS(string message) {
            int n;
            wchar_t ucs2[1000];
            char utf8[1000];
            n = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, message.c_str(), message.size(), ucs2, 1000);
            n = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, ucs2, n, utf8, 1000, 0, 0);
            return std::string(utf8, n);
        }

        static string SJIS_to_UTF8(std::string const& message)      {
            int n;
            wchar_t ucs2[1000];
            char utf8[1000];
            n = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, message.c_str(), message.size(), ucs2, 1000);
            n = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, ucs2, n, utf8, 1000, 0, 0);
            return std::string(utf8, n);
        }

        // string から wstring 変換
        static wstring StringToWString(const string& refSrc, unsigned int codePage = CodePageID::ANSI) {
            vector<wchar_t> buffer(MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, refSrc.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0));
            MultiByteToWideChar(codePage, 0, refSrc.c_str(), -1, &buffer.front(), buffer.size());
            return wstring(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
        }

        // wstring から string 変換
        static string WStringToString(const wstring& refSrc, unsigned int codePage = CodePageID::OEM) {
            vector<char> buffer(WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, refSrc.c_str(), -1, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr));
            WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, refSrc.c_str(), -1, &buffer.front(), buffer.size(), nullptr, nullptr);
            return string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
        }

        static string EraseString(string str, string erase) {
            for (size_t c = str.find_first_of(erase); c != string::npos; c = c = str.find_first_of(erase)) {
                str.erase(c, 1);
            }
            return str;
        }
    }

    namespace REST {

        static string GET(Request req) {
            try {
                using namespace CAIOS::String;

                http_client client(StringToWString(req.url));
                http_request request(methods::GET);

                cout << " -> HTTP request mode [GET]" << endl;
                cout << " -> HTTP request to " << req.url << endl;

                request.headers().add(L"Content-Type", L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.headers().add(L"Authorization", StringToWString(req.header));

                http_response response = client.request(request).get(); //ここで例外
                auto str = response.extract_string();

                cout << " -> Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << '.' << endl;
                cout << " -> Content length is " << response.headers().content_length() << " bytes.\n" << endl;

                ofstream ofs(REST_GET_PATH);
                ofs << WStringToString(str.get().c_str()) << endl;
                ofs.close();

                return WStringToString(str.get().c_str());
            }
            catch (exception & error) {
                cout << error.what() << endl;
                return "HTTP通信中に例外が発生しました　[GET]  ";
            }
        }

        static string POST(Request req) {
            try {
                using namespace CAIOS::String;

                http_client client(StringToWString(req.url));

                http_request request(methods::POST);

                cout << " -> HTTP request mode [POST]" << endl;
                cout << " -> HTTP request to " << req.url << endl;

                request.headers().add(L"Content-Type", L"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.set_body(req.post);

                http_response response = client.request(request).get();
                auto str = response.extract_string();

                cout << " -> Server returned returned status code " << response.status_code() << '.' << endl;
                cout << " -> Content length is " << response.headers().content_length() << " bytes.\n" << endl;

                ofstream ofs(REST_POST_PATH);
                ofs << WStringToString(str.get().c_str()) << endl;
                ofs.close();

                return WStringToString(str.get().c_str());
            }
            catch (...) {
                return "HTTP通信中に例外が発生しました　[POST]";
            }
        }

        static string URL_encode(string str) {
            const int NUM_BEGIN_UTF8 = 48;
            const int CAPITAL_BEGIN_UTF8 = 65;
            const int LOWER_BEGIN_UTF8 = 97;

            int charCode = -1;
            string encoded;
            stringstream out;

            for (int i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
                charCode = (int)(unsigned char)str[i];

                //エンコードする必要の無い文字の判定
                if ((NUM_BEGIN_UTF8 <= charCode && charCode <= NUM_BEGIN_UTF8 + 9)
                    || (CAPITAL_BEGIN_UTF8 <= charCode && charCode <= CAPITAL_BEGIN_UTF8 + 25)
                    || (LOWER_BEGIN_UTF8 <= charCode && charCode <= LOWER_BEGIN_UTF8 + 25)
                    || str[i] == '.' || str[i] == '_' || str[i] == '-' || str[i] == '~'){
                    out << str[i];
                }
                else {
                    out << '%' << hex << uppercase << charCode;
                }
            }
            encoded = out.str();
            return encoded;
        }
    }

    namespace Twitter {
        namespace OAuth {
            static string CreateAuthorization(vector<string>const Option, int Start1, vector<string>const OAuth, int Start2) {
                string Authorization = "OAuth ";

                for (int t = Start1; t < Option.size(); t++) {
                    Authorization += Option[t] + ",";
                }
                for (int t = Start2; t < OAuth.size(); t++) {
                    Authorization += OAuth[t] + ",";
                }

                Authorization.pop_back();
                return Authorization;
            }

            static string CreateData(vector<string>const OAuth, METHOD method, int Start) {
                string query;

                if (method == POST) {
                    for (int t = Start; t < OAuth.size(); t++) {
                        if (t != Start)query += "&";
                        query += OAuth[t];
                    }
                }
                else if (method == GET) {
                    for (int t = Start; t < OAuth.size(); t++) {
                        query += OAuth[t];
                        if (t == Start)query += "?";
                        else query += "&";
                    }
                    query.pop_back();
                }

                return query;
            }

            static int split_url(const string url, vector<string>* Option, vector<string>* OAuth) {
                int num = url.find_first_of('?');
                OAuth->push_back(url.substr(0, num));
                OAuth->push_back(url.substr(num + 1));
                Option->push_back(url.substr(0, num));
                Option->push_back(url.substr(num + 1));
                return 0;
            }

            static string sha1(const string Key, const string Data) {
                char* key = (char*)Key.c_str();
                char* data = (char*)Data.c_str();
                unsigned char res[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH + 1];
                size_t reslen;

                HMAC(EVP_sha1(), key, strlen(key), reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data), strlen(data), res, &reslen);

                return string(reinterpret_cast<char*>(res), reslen);
            }

            static int encode_base64(char* bufin, int len, char* bufout){
                static unsigned char base64[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
                unsigned char* pin = (unsigned char*)bufin;
                unsigned char* pout = (unsigned char*)bufout;

                for (int i = 0; i < len - 2; i += 3){
                    *pout++ = base64[pin[0] >> 2];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & ((pin[0] << 4) | (pin[1] >> 4))];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & ((pin[1] << 2) | (pin[2] >> 6))];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & pin[2]];
                    pin += 3;
                }
                if (len % 3 == 1){
                    *pout++ = base64[pin[0] >> 2];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & (pin[0] << 4)];
                    *pout++ = '=';
                    *pout++ = '=';
                }
                else if (len % 3 == 2){
                    *pout++ = base64[pin[0] >> 2];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & ((pin[0] << 4) | (pin[1] >> 4))];
                    *pout++ = base64[0x3F & (pin[1] << 2)];
                    *pout++ = '=';
                }
                *pout = '\0';
                return pout - (unsigned char*)bufout;
            }

            static string CreateSignature(string ConsumerSecret, string AccessSecret, vector<string>const& OAuth, METHOD method, int Start = 1) {
                string str, key, data, methods;
                char out[256];

                if (method == POST)methods = "POST";
                else methods = "GET";

                key = CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(ConsumerSecret) + "&" + CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(AccessSecret);

                data = methods + "&" + CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(OAuth[0]) + "&" + CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(CreateData(OAuth, method, Start));

                str = sha1(key, data);

                CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::encode_base64((char*)str.c_str(), str.size(), out);

                return CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(out);
            }

            static int IntOAuthParams(vector<string>* OAuth, METHOD method) {
                TwitterAPI_Keys key;

                auto CreateNonce = []() {
                    static const char* chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_";
                    const unsigned int max = 26 + 26 + 10 + 1;
                    char tmp[50];
                    srand((unsigned int)time(0));
                    int len = 15 + rand() % 16;
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                        tmp[i] = chars[rand() % max];
                    }
                    return std::string(tmp, len);
                };

                string oauth_nonce = "oauth_nonce";
                oauth_nonce += "=";
                oauth_nonce += CreateNonce();
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_nonce);

                string oauth_timestamp = "oauth_timestamp";
                oauth_timestamp += "=";
                oauth_timestamp += to_string((int)time(nullptr));
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_timestamp);

                string oauth_token = "oauth_token";
                oauth_token += "=";
                oauth_token += key.Accesstoken;
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_token);

                string oauth_consumer_key = "oauth_consumer_key";
                oauth_consumer_key += "=";
                oauth_consumer_key += key.Consumer_Key;
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_consumer_key);

                string oauth_signature_method = "oauth_signature_method";
                oauth_signature_method += "=";
                oauth_signature_method += "HMAC-SHA1";
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_signature_method);

                string oauth_version = "oauth_version";
                oauth_version += "=";
                oauth_version += "1.0";
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_version);

                sort(OAuth->begin() + 1, OAuth->end());

                string oauth_signature = "oauth_signature";
                oauth_signature += "=";
                oauth_signature += CreateSignature(key.Consumer_Sec, key.Accesstoken_Aec, *OAuth, method);
                OAuth->push_back(oauth_signature);

                return 0;
            }

            static Request OAuthAuthentication(string url, METHOD method) {
                vector<string> OAuth;
                vector<string> Option;

                CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::split_url(url, &Option, &OAuth);

                CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::IntOAuthParams(&OAuth, method);

                Request req;

                if (method == POST) {
                    req.url = OAuth[0];
                    req.post = CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::CreateData(OAuth, method, 1);
                    req.header = "";
                }
                else if (method == GET) {
                    req.url = CAIOS::Twitter::OAuth::CreateData(Option, method, 0);
                    req.post = "";
                    req.header = CreateAuthorization(Option, 1, OAuth, 2);
                }

                return req;
            }
        }

        static string Tweet(string message) {
            message = CAIOS::String::SJIS_to_UTF8(message);

            string url = TWITTER_TWEET_URL;
            url += "?status=" + CAIOS::REST::URL_encode(message);

            Request req = OAuth::OAuthAuthentication(url, POST);
            return CAIOS::REST::POST(req);
        }

        static string TimeLine(int num) {
            string url = TWITTER_TIMELINE_URL;
            url += "?count=" + to_string(num);

            Request req = OAuth::OAuthAuthentication(url, GET);
            return CAIOS::REST::GET(req);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

リクエストヘッダーの文字数の上限が56なんてことはありえません。そんなに短ければ、一般的によく使用するようなリクエストヘッダーでもすぐに制限に引っかかってしまいます。

> From my experience, a username with 56 characters is still OK. You can check it at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783323.aspx and the permitted length of username is 256 characters

前半の「56」は「256」のtypoでしょう。後半で「the permitted length of username is 256 characters」と言っているので。ただ、この引用しているページもActive Directoryのユーザー名の制限についての解説ページなので、本件とは無関係でしょうね。

C++の文法はよく分かりませんが、少なくともこの行は間違っていますよね。

```cpp
request.headers().add(L"Authorization", StringToWString(req.header));
```

別のリクエストのヘッダー全体を文字列化したものを、`Authorization`ヘッダーにセットしているように見えます。

APIの仕様をよく読んで、適切なリクエストを送信するように修正して下さい。